# Kusto extract text between string

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Am trying to use regex to extract a string between a set of strings. But Kusto complains about the regex expression as invalid.

Am trying to replicate the expression from this [link](https://regexr.com/2tr28) in my kusto query.

```
traces
| where ....
| project  extract_all(@"(?<=This is)(.*)(?=sentence)", message)
```

Kusto would complain this error..

```
Relop semantic error: 'extractall' has the following semantic error: SEM0420: Regex pattern is ill-formed: (?<=This is)(.*)(?=sentence).
If issue persists, please open a support ticket. Request id: 01b819be-2e11-4983-9312-30f946c07afb
```

Could someone please help me fix the syntax of the above regex for kusto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as the error message suggests, the regular expression you're specifying as the argument to the `extract_all()` method is invalid.

from the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/re2

> The regular expression syntax supported by Kusto is that of the [re2 library](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

If you were to provide a sample input and the matching expected output, it'd be easier to provide you with a functional and efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks @Yoni. I changed to RE2 syntax and its working now...
extract(@"SMTP: ([^|]*)\.", 1,message) 
Sentencte am searching is "SMTP: XXXXXX." and the above would extract XXXXXX